# Acessing inner element of JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, element

How to access inner element of a JSON array. My Json object is as follows:

```
"numRecommenders": 0,
    "publicProfileUrl": "http://www.linkedin.com/pub/heena-vyas/16/786/826",
    "positions": {
        "total": 1,
        "positionList": [
            {
                "id": "91286566",
                "title": "senior executive",
                "company": {
                    "name": "Reliance",
                    "industry": "Oil & Energy",
                    "type": "Public Company",
                    "size": "10,001+ employees"
                },
                "isCurrent": true
            }
        ]
    },
```

I want to access `positions.positionList.company.name`.
My requirement is to run a `GroupCommand` as follows:

```
GroupCommand cmd = new GroupCommand(collection,
        null,
        new BasicDBObject("positions.positionList.company.name", "Reliance"),
        new BasicDBObject("count", 0),
        "function(obj,prev) {prev.count++;}",
        null);
```

Accessing 'name' using above code is not working.  Can someone please give me an answer to why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = jsonObject.positions.positionlist[0].company.name;
```

Note that your `positionlist` is an array of length `jsonObject.positions.total`.